# how to use mutiple filters in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have html code includin dropdown which I have used filter.

```
<div class="controls">
    <label class="control-label" for="teamRole">Select Rater: </label>
    <select name="selectReviewForm" data-ng-model="firstName" data-ng-options="getDisplayName(rf) for rf in users |filter: 'Associates' ">
    <option value="">-please select-</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here I want to use multiple filters, can any one guide me how can I use it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can *chain* your filters with the `|` character as you would typically do in a Linux shell :

```
{{ value | number: 42 | currency: '$' }}
```

In the case of filter chaining, each filter will receive on its input the output of the previous filter.